# Access from change event to other input html jquery autocreate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

My problem is:

I have a page with a table is auto generated with ajax-jquery

My table is 3 `<td>` 1: name 2-3: checkbox for parameters

I set event on all input:checkbox ("change") event.

The problem appears when i try to get check state of checkbox different than i click.

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#permessiAttributiDiv").on("change", "input:checkbox", function() {
        var IDPermesso = $(this).attr("id").substring(1);
        var selezionatoSpuntato = (this.checked);
        var altro = $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").checked;
        var scheda = $("#selectTipo").val();
    });
)};
```

I also try to get check state by id but i always doesn't work......

I see if the checkbox is write in html static code all works ok but if i generate it with jquery i can't access to input with any selector.....

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be getting error in console. See [How to open the JavaScript console in different browsers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

The problem line which I see is

```
var altro = $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").checked;
```

As `$(this).parent().find("input:checkbox")` will return you jQuery object and they don't have `checked` property.

You can use `.not(this)` to exclude the current element from the collection.

```
var altro = $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").not(this).prop('checked');
```

*OR*

```
var altro = $(this).parent().find("input:checkbox").not(this).is(':checked');
```